# How to Change Default Blocks/Section In Joomla 3.2.1?

Tags: php, html, css, moodle

[image: a image with red container]

I want to remove this section in red container. Please suggest what I should do to solve this issue?

Comment: A link to the live website might help.

Comment: no this website is running on my localhost

Comment: The first place I'd check is Menus -> Main Menu -> Learning -> Page Page Display -> Page Heading. If this doesn't help, inspecting the unwanted text with FireBug or Developer Tools or similar might help narrow down the search to a menu heading or a module or something else.

Answer (score 0):

The first place I'd check is Menus -> Main Menu -> Learning -> Page Page Display -> Page Heading.

If this doesn't help, inspecting the unwanted text with FireBug or Developer Tools or similar might help narrow down the search to a menu heading or a module or something else.

Without access to the site or more information, answers here will only be a guess.